# Can someone explain why I need to use the void *sum_thread(void *data) prototype?

Tags: c, multithreading

```
void * sum_thread(void *data)
{
}

pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, sum_thread, &arrdata[i]);
```

Comment: Function will return void pointer. That's why you need it.

Comment: Just read the POSIX specification for pthreads and it should become clear

Answer (score 1):

This is because that's the combination of return value type (`void *`) and argument list (a single `void *`) that was chosen by the designers of the pthreads API (to which `pthread_create()` belongs).

All programs that start threads using this API need to give it a thread function with that exact prototype. You can read documentation (like [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)) to find out more about how this call works.

It's a decently generic way to represent "any data" in C.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the function pointer format expected by pthreads, so your callback function must have that format. There's nothing to understand about it, it is simply something specified by the POSIX standard.

`man pthread_create` gives:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Would you pass any other kind of function pointer, it would violate the C standard and the POSIX standard both, and you invoke undefined behavior.